# How to properly return a collection of unique_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, unique-ptr

After changing my code to use unique pointers, I stumbled upon how to return a collection of objects to a client. In general, I want to pass objects as references or non-owning pointers. But if I have a collection of objects, I can't just return the reference to it.

As an example, I have a simple class with a collection of objects, which are all created once and not altered afterwards.

```cpp
using ObjectUPtr = std::unique_ptr<Object>;
class MyClass
{
  public:
  const std::vector<Object*>& GetObjectsOldStyle() const
  {
    return mObjectsOldStyle;
  }

  const std::vector<VObjectUPtr>& GetObjectsNewStyleA() const
  {
    // I don't like that: The client should not see the unique_ptr ...
    return mObjectsNewStyle; 
  }

  std::vector<VObject*> GetObjectsNewStyleB() const
  {
    // Ok, but performance drops
    std::transform(...); // Transform the collection and return a copy
  }

  const std::vector<VObject*>& GetObjectsNewStyleC() const
  {
    // Ok, only copied once, but two variables per collection needed
    // Transform the collection and cache in a second vector<Object*>
    std::transform(...);
  }

  std::vector<Object*> mObjectsOldStyle;    // old-style owning pointers here
  std::vector<ObjectUPtr> mObjectsNewStyle; // how I want to do it today
}
```

Today, I usually prefer GetObjectsNewStyleB, but I wonder, if there is a more elegant and efficient way or a general best practice on how to return such collections.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would recommend creating your own iterator class. Then create begin and end member functions. You can even overload the dereference operator to return references, instead of pointers (unless your pointers might be null). It might start something like this:

```
class iterator :
    public std::iterator<std::random_access_iterator_tag, Object>
{
public:
    Object& operator*() const { return **base; }
    Object* operator->() const { return &**base; }
    iterator& operator++() { ++base; return *this; }

    // several other members necessary for random access iterators
private:
    std::vector<ObjectUPtr>::iterator base;
};
```

It's a bit tedious implementing a standard conforming iterator, but I think this is by far the most idiomatic solution. As mentioned in the comments, the Boost.Iterator library, specifically [`boost::iterator_facade`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/iterator/doc/iterator_facade.html) can be used to relieve some of the tedium.

Comment: Also, some of the tedium can be avoided by using `boost.iterator` to implement this.

Comment: If I get you right, this means implementing a kind of wrapper for the stl container (e.g. as described here: http://accu.org/index.php/journals/1527). I tried that and it's nice to use in a way like 

    for (auto obj : myClass.Objects) { ... }

However, it means I need to write a wrapper for all collections in my model. I already do that, but I somehow hoped for an easier way with a direct conversion for any kind of stl container with unique_ptr to raw pointer.

Comment: I tried your solution: works great and the API is what I wanted.
There is still one little thing left that is tricky: If I store objects in my container, but I want to return pure interfaces on those objects at the API: 
In this case, I cannot use the iterator because I need knowledge about the underlying object type. I could solve this by using a second container in parallel to the "owning" container, but that seems kind of weird.
The receiver solution of Adam below is more flexible here, but also not exactly what I'd expect from a simple API giving access to a collection.

Comment: @badstoms: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean by "return pure interfaces on those objects at the API". It's a bit vague.

Comment: @Benjamin: I meant a secondary problem, which is independent of this problem: 
VObject derives from IObject (a pure interface)
You store a collection of VObjects, but you want to return a collection of IObjects (as pure interfaces) to the client.
I guess, a transformation/copy is inevitable. You can't bend the iterators, since they are copied.

Answer (score 6):

You don't have to *return the collection*, thus break the encapsulation of the container class. There are other options.

I would go with Enumerator/Receiver pattern (I don't know if this is the actual name for this pattern).

The basic idea is to have the client of your API implement an interface which in principle receives objects from a container one by one.

It looks like this:

```
class Receiver {
  public:
    virtual void receive(const Object& object) = 0;
};

class Container {
  public:
    void enumerate(Receiver& receiver) const {
      for (auto&& obj : m_objects) {
        receiver.receive(*obj);
      }
    }

  private:
    std::vector<ObjectUPtr> m_objects;
};
```

Then implement the Receiver interface:

```
class ReceiverImpl : public Receiver {
  public:
    virtual void receive(const Object& object) {
      // do something with object
    }  
};
```

and have the container enumerate the objects to the receiver:

```
Container container;
ReceiverImpl receiver;
container.enumerate(receiver);
```

See [live example](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/FMX9voebumZA9Zcs).

Moreover you could even make the container thread-safe simply by adding a mutex lock/unlock in `Container::enumerate` and the client won't even notice!

Finally you could replace the receiver argument in `Container::enumerate` with a template argument to get rid of the run-time overhead of virtual function calls.

Comment: This would make the random access to an element more complicated. But I now understand (and agree with you), that exposing the stl container directly is a bad idea for numerous reasons.

Comment: Right, but still... You could add `Container::enumerate(std::size_t idx, Receiver& receiver)` overload to the container class to provide a facility for random access. In general this issue is about a trade-off between encapsulation and usability.

Answer (score 4):

If using boost I prefer `tranform_iterator` over `iterator_facade` in such cases.

To get a more functional style I split up the code into two parts:

- create a class that can hold two pointers as a range (allows range based for loops).
- create a function that takes a lambda as transformation step and returns a range (to hide `transform_iterator`).

Thus the transformation step is executed on dereferencing the iterator.

### Code Sample

```
#include <boost/iterator/transform_iterator.hpp>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

#include <stdio.h>

using namespace boost;
using namespace std;

template <typename Iterator>
class Range {
    public:
        Range(Iterator begin, Iterator end) : b(begin), e(end) { }
        Range(const Range &r) = default;
        Range(Range &&r) = default;
        Range &operator=(const Range &r) = default;
        Range &operator=(Range &&r) = default;

        template <typename Container>
            Range(Container &c) : b(c.begin()), e(c.end()) { }

        Iterator begin() { return b;}
        Iterator begin() const { return b; }

        Iterator end() { return e;}
        Iterator end() const { return e; }

        Iterator b;
        Iterator e;
};


template <typename Container, typename TransformFunc>
Range<transform_iterator<TransformFunc, typename Container::iterator>>
transform(Container &c, TransformFunc f) {
    using namespace boost;
    using cont_it = typename Container::iterator;
    using iterator = transform_iterator<TransformFunc, cont_it>;

    iterator b = iterator(c.begin(), f), e = iterator(c.end(), f);
    Range<iterator> r(b,e);

    return r;
}

int main(int, char **) {
    vector<unique_ptr<int>> foo;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        foo.push_back(unique_ptr<int>(new int(10)));
    }

    auto f = [](unique_ptr<int> &i) { return i.get(); };
    for (auto *i : transform(foo, f) ) {
        printf("%p ", i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```